# Skrollr: how to start animation only once a certain point is reached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, skrollr

I'm playing with [skrollr plugin](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) but can't achieve what I want so looking for assistance.
I've been able to implement easy effects such as `<div id="intro-left" data-0="opacity: 0" data-180="opacity: 1">` (means that my DIV called intro-left becomes visible once user scrolls down by 180)

The issue is that I don't like to use the scrolling distance since this would only makes sense  if everone had the same screen resolution right?

What I'd like to do is to tell skrollr: "Change DIV from opacity 0 to opacity 1 once the DIV position becomes visible on the screen" (in other words "Change DIV from opacity 0 to opacity 1 once user reaches a certain point on the page by scrolling down)

Is this achievable with skrollr, and how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#relative-mode-or-viewport-mode)?

There's even an example demonstrating [different anchors](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/anchors.html)

In short:

```
<div id="intro-left" data-bottom-top="opacity: 0" data-center="opacity: 1">
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I saw this example but did not understand it. Now with you're explanation I'm getting the concept! Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 @Prinzhorn great documentation, particularly the section you linked to - that's hard to explain but it's clear! Great library too, thanks!